# Raspberry Pi 5 + Google WiFi: Sounds like a NAT issue, but doesn't seem so

Tags: networking, ethernet, port-forwarding, google-nest

**Background.** I tend to have a raspberry at home running some services (ssh, svn, apache, vpn) that I can access from the outside world.  A few days ago I upgraded my hardware from a raspberry pi 3 (RPi3) to a new raspberry pi 5 (RPi5) and started migrating all these services to the new raspberry.   (This upgrade was an opportunity as I was running low on HD space in RPi3.)

Furthermore, for my network at home I have Google WiFi (mesh; indeed Google WiFi, not Nest, nor Nest Pro) and I manage everything via the Google Home App.  My internet provider is AT&T and I am using an IP passthrough so that everything is managed by the Google WiFi devices.

**RPis are using ethernet.** All my RPis are connected via their ethernet ports either directly to a Google WiFi device, or via a switch that is connected via ethernet to the Google WiFi device.

**All well after initial upgrade.** After purchasing the RPi5, initially everything was fine.  I could ssh, commit and update my svn repos, see webpages being served by apache, and use wireguard (I used to work with OpenVPN in the previous raspberry).  So, all the port forwarding would occur as expected and the services were running fine.

**Clouds in the horizon.** Fast forward 1-2 days later, I did not like the LAN IP of the RPi5 and I tried to assign a new LAN IP to my RPi5.  However, the RPi5 would not obtain the new "dedicated" IP upon reboot, unless, I would give:

```
$ sudo dhclient -r eth0
$ sudo dhclient eth0
```

However, this would be unstable!  After a reboot, I could see RPi5 getting the old IP (with some probability -- not always), which was not meant for it, and naturally port-forwarding would break.  So, I decided to go back and allow RPi5 to have the LAN IP it showed preference.  Around the same time I installed OpenVPN as well -- let's say due to a friend's suggestion.

After the above two events (fixing the LAN IP to what RPi5 wanted and installed OpenVPN), RPi5 would not offer many services, or offer them intermittently.  In particular, I can no longer login at the RPi5 at home via ssh from the outside world, receiving a "connection refused" message.  However, I can establish a connection, if I redirect incoming traffic to port 22 to the old RPi3 that is running at home!

Same is true for apache.  Should I redirect my incoming requests to the new RPi5, I can see a message "Invalid Host header".  Should I redirect incoming requests to port 80, then RPi3 serves content as expected to the outside world!!

**Impossible to even shutdown the RPi5.** Coming back to ssh, sometime today morning I started getting a "connection refused" message for attempts that I did in order to login via ssh using the LAN IP of RPi5.  In other words, even if I am not attempting to reach the brand new RPi5 from the outside world, I may still find the door closed while I am on the same LAN! This means that the only way to shutdown the RPi5, is if unplug it from the wall socket.

**Troubleshooting steps that I have tried**

- I have tried using as main router two out of the three Google WiFi devices that I have and the result is identical in both of them.
- Port forwarding to the same/similar services offered by the wanna-retire RPi3 works great!  However, not so for RPi5.
- I have completely uninstalled both Wireguard and OpenVPN.  Both had been installed via pivpn.

**Other observations**

- I noticed that when RPi3 joined the network, I would get a message through the Google Home App telling me that the particular device called, say, "RPi3" has joined my network.  However, this *never* happened when I used RPi5 -- I never got such a message (and I made sure that I would plug into the network the RPi5 alone as I was testing for this purpose).
- Along these lines, RPi3 would appear as "RPi3" in the list of devices shown through the Google Home App, but RPi5 would be recognized as "unknown" device and I would have to specifically find the RPi5 and give it a name through the Google Home App.  So, perhaps there is some issue with some "bonjour" (or something ...) service?  This is odd, given that RPi5 is the "latest and greatest"!  One would find reasonable the opposite observations, but not this.
- ssh may work intermittently for RPi5 even if I am on the same LAN!
- Now that I have RPi5 on the network, I find the Google Home WiFi to behave oddly.  In particular, it may show in the app that the network for my home is "Offline" and in case this is true, then I cannot make any changes on port forwarding, reserving IP addresses for devices, etc.  This typically does not last long, or may stop being an issue if I specifically try to find the devices in the app and then going back to the previous screen would show the network to be in "Great" shape.  By the way, I have internet access on my devices when this issue occurs.  So, I am thinking it should be something in RPi5 that is really confusing the Google WiFi router.  But what would that be?

*Does anyone have any idea on what might be causing this issue and more importantly how it can be resolved?  Any ideas on what troubleshooting steps we can take to figure out what is wrong?  All help is more than welcome!*

**Network Configuration.** I have the following network topology at the moment:

```
[ATT Router using IP Passthrough] -> [Google WiFi 1] -> Switch -> RPi5 
[Google WiFi 2] -> RPi3
Above, all links (->) show connections using ftp/ethernet cable
```

Please note that RPi5 took the place of RPi3 in the switch above when I made the upgrade.
I manage all the networking through the Google Home App. If you need more specific information, please ask a specific question.

**Some more information on the network.**
All my devices obtain IPs in the network via DHCP from Google WiFi.  I will then make a reservation for the particular host by making a reservation in the Google Home App (Home > Wifi > Network Settings > Advanced Networking > DHCP IP reservations > reserve an IP for a device; in particular for RPi3 and RPi5).

Here is RPi3:

```
$ uname -a
Linux RPi3 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
$
```

Here is RPi5:

```
$ uname -a
Linux RPi5 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux
$
```

Here is some output on RPi5:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b | grep eth0
Mar 14 20:38:37 RPi5 kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: Cadence GEM rev 0x00070109 at 0x1f00100000 irq 107 (d8:3a:dd:f3:3a:a4)
Mar 14 20:38:40 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466720.1640] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Mar 14 20:38:40 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466720.1645] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 14 20:38:40 RPi5 kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: PHY [1f00100000.ethernet-ffffffff:01] driver [Broadcom BCM54213PE] (irq=POLL)
Mar 14 20:38:40 RPi5 kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: configuring for phy/rgmii-id link mode
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2817] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2819] device (eth0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2831] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (660afa1d-e80b-3dfa-b1b1-9a21b7bdc5a1)
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2832] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2835] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2839] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 kernel: macb 1f00100000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.2847] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.86.91.
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Registering new address record for 192.168.86.91 on eth0.IPv4.
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::c526:c68f:f200:3a4f.
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.3146] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Registering new address record for fe80::c526:c68f:f200:3a4f on eth0.*.
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.3160] device (eth0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.3161] device (eth0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 14 20:38:44 RPi5 NetworkManager[835]: <info>  [1710466724.3165] device (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mar 14 20:38:46 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::c526:c68f:f200:3a4f.
Mar 14 20:38:46 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fd44:dbd3:33a5:6af5:7dc8:fbe9:9994:1e3e.
Mar 14 20:38:46 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Registering new address record for fd44:dbd3:33a5:6af5:7dc8:fbe9:9994:1e3e on eth0.*.
Mar 14 20:38:46 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c526:c68f:f200:3a4f on eth0.
Mar 14 20:46:50 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Registering new address record for fe80::c526:c68f:f200:3a4f on eth0.*.
Mar 14 20:47:00 RPi5 avahi-daemon[631]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c526:c68f:f200:3a4f on eth0.
$
```

P.S.: I have made a similar post while waiting moderator's approval to the Raspberry Pi Forums.  That post is now online and there is discussion there too.  Here is the link:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=367430

Comment: This post is totally devoid of any meaningful technical data about what you actually did or diagnostics - in particular HOW you configured networking.

Comment: @Milliways I have updated the post explaining the network topology if that is what you wanted to know.  I also manage everything via the Google Home app.  If you want to know something else, can you ask a more specific question?  Perhaps something that can be the outcome of a command?  I would be more than happy to provide you with an answer once I know what you would like to know.  Thank you for all the help!